# Magento site is in maintenance mode

Tags: magento, maintenance-mode

I recently installed an extension in my magento site through magento connect.I forgot to uncheck `put magento site to maintenance mode` check box.Installation failed due to some unknown reason.I am unable goto magento frontend.it still in maintenance mode.how do i change magento to production mode.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto your magento root installation .there should be a file named `maintanence.flag`.delete that file and check your magento frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Goto   htdocs in Xampp folder where you installed magento then delete the file name maintanence.flag After refresh your homepage or admin page in browser.

Comment: If any one use Wamp server then he is not found Xampp folder so no need to maintain Xampp folder just used root directory .